# Handle Session Timeout while postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-timeout

I have a web application developed in ASP.net & C#. I also use Telerik ASP.NET AJAX for web UI. Session time out is handled in master page as following :

```
public partial class Master: System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["UserName"] == null)
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
}
```

this works fine if i try to load a page after session time out. but if i try to perform a postback it throws NullReferenceException.

Is there any way to redirect to login page after session time out and while doing postback? or how to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You have to handle this scenario using session_start event in global.asax , because after a session timeout, if the user once more cause a post back, the Session_Start()
event is fired.

Please look [here](http://www.abstraction.net/ViewArticle.aspx?articleID=74) how you can put logic.

Answer (score 1):

Using `if(Session.IsNew)` is one approach to take.